# Sequence .Net Tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, .net-4.0

I have several `Task` objects, such as `Task<int>`, `Task<string>`, `Task<double>`, that I want to run sequentially. That is, as each Task completes the next Task starts automatically.  Each task depends on the output from the prior task.

How do I do this?  The myTask.ContinueWith(...) overloads all assume a delegate parameter.  But a Task is not a delegate.

Comment: Have you gone over this page on [continuation tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372288.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)

Comment: Make the delegate passed to myTask.ContinueWith(...) start the next task. Alternatively, in situations where you schedule your tasks on the thread pool, and their ordered execution is paramount, I have found the LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351.aspx) with maxDegreeOfParallelism = 1, to be great help.

Comment: @KirillShlenskiy you should make that an answer. The existing answers are not as good as your solution.

Comment: See also this example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537612.aspx

Answer (score 3):

<strike>You could do like:</strike>

```cs
var t1 = new Task(() => Console.WriteLine("Completed t1"));
var t2 = new Task(() => Console.WriteLine("Completed t2"));
var t3 = new Task(() => Console.WriteLine("Completed t3"));

t1.ContinueWith(t => t2.RunSynchronously())
    .ContinueWith(t => t3.RunSynchronously());

t1.Start();
```

---

The example above only works, if you don't care about the results of the tasks. If you however (as your edit states), need to pass the result of each task to the next task, then you could do something like:

```cs
var t1 = new Task(() => Console.WriteLine("Completed t1"));
var t2 = new Task(() => Console.WriteLine("Completed t2"));
var t3 = new Task(() => Console.WriteLine("Completed t3"));

t1.ContinueWith(task1 =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(task1.Result);

    t2.ContinueWith(task2 =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} | {1}", task1.Result, task2.Result);

        t3.ContinueWith(task3 =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} | {1} | {2}", 
                task1.Result, task2.Result, task3.Result);
        });

        t3.Start();
    });

    t2.Start();
});

t1.Start();

/* OUTPUT:
Completed t1
Completed t1 | Completed t2
Completed t1 | Completed t2 | Completed t3 */
```

Comment: I believe your second example is not necessary. If you want the results, use the first example and just wait for `t3` to finish. When it has finished you can get to the results of each task individually via the `Task.Result` property on each of the task instances (`t1`, `t2`, `t3`).